# Direction of a system of particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I read in a book that a system of particles should have identical acceleration. Suppose the given figure. It is written that $G$ and $C$ cannot be considered as a system of particles as the acceleration is in different directions. But on Khan Academy he told that particles should only have magnitude of acceleration equal and we can consider them as a system.

Please clear this doubt.[image]

Comment: None of the planets in the solar system have the same acceleration. Or the same magnitude of acceleration. They’re still called a system. You should find another book and another website.

Comment: Can you cite the article ?

Answer (score 0):

i guess anything made of particles can be called a system of particles... and certainly these particles may have their own acceleration. Are you sure you got that definition right?

Comment: Actually, I asked this question in reference to solving problems in Newton's Laws of Motion. So, for that it was written in book that all particles in the system should be connected and have same acceleration(with direction too).